# express - How to path to express jade views

Tags: node.js, express, pug

If I path to a view in `./views` express will render it but it doesn't that for example `./views/api/login.jade` and it send `500: Internal Server Error`.

my codes:

```
/* GET api/...  */
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('api/login.jade', { title: 'Login' });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: without .jade  `res.render('api/login', { title: 'Login' });`

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the views path as well.

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('api/login', { title: 'Login' });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

#### step 1: you have to make sure you are using jade as the view engine.

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

#### step 2: set view path

```
app.set('views', __dirname);
```

or you can write it in every render call, `res.render(__dirname+'api/login')`

#### Step 3: do not write extension names

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('api/login', { title: 'Login' });
});
```

#### P.S.

i recommend that you start using `pug` instead of `jade` since pug is jade 2.0

Comment: I done steps one and two but it still shows same message!